# In codeigniter, How to get the token returned from google login as parameter to controller?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I am working with AuthSub to view portfolios of google finance api on codeigniter framework.

after successful login of google it redirects to the url we provide.

I have provided url like: `www.finance.mysite.com/google/token/`

google will append its token like:

```
www.finance.mysite.com/google/token/?token=1/gyXbtvKT4XaIuUIhEBAsuxyDgATMDk3ztAG3MocNkKI
```

How can I get it inside a function token() inside google controller.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that you have control over "how" it gives it to you.  For a controller parameter, you'll need to redirect after the Auth callback "gives" you the token.  This is probably unnecessary though, as you can simply grab it out of the query string.

```
<?php
$token = $this->input->get('token');
if ($token)
{
    // Option 1: redirect to a controller action that
    //           takes the token as the parameter
    redirect('/google/token/'.$token);

    // Option 2: do something directly with the token
    //           right now (why bother redirecting?)
    var_dump($token);
    exit;
}
die('Access token? We didn\'t get no access token!');
?>
```

Storing the token in the session or database is an alternative to the redirect, but the redirect would how to "get the token as parameter to controller" like you ask.

Comment: google appends "?token=aldkfjasldfkKJH444lkj" to whatever url we provide like i have provided finance.mysite.com/google/token/

Answer (score 0):

Just extract the token, and route it to controller of your choice. 
You can extract the params like this

```
$params = "http://www.finance.mysite.com/google/token/?token=1/gyXbtvKT4XaIuUIhEBAsuxyDgATMDk3ztAG3MocNkKI";
$parsed = parse_url($params);
$pieces = explode("=", $parsed['query']);
$searchIndex = array_search("token", $pieces);
if($searchIndex) {
    $token = $pieces[$searchIndex+1];
    //now use it as you need
    redirect("controller/google/$token");
}
```

<sub>Note: The code above will only work, if there is only single parameter on the url, or else not.</sub>